# in Retina display, in canvas no svg file set properly in paper js

Tags: canvas, retina-display, paperjs

**Retina Display : When user open large kit on canvas and see in small screen, it doesn't fit into screen.**

I have tested in Mac-book 12-13 inch retina screen.
I already did some operation like

```
canvas.width = width * ratio;
canvas.height = height * ratio;
$(canvas).css("width", width+"px").css("height", height+"px");
context.scale(ratio,ratio);
context.save();
```

Comment: For changing the canvas size in paperjs, it would be better to use `view.viewSize`.
For scaling in paperjs, it would be better to use `view.zoom`.
The reference is http://paperjs.org/reference/view/

Answer (score 0):

I use zooming to solve this issue

```
function getInitialZoomRatio(svgWidth, svgHeight) {
    if (svgWidth > paper.project.view.element.width || svgHeight > paper.project.view.element.height) {
        var wRatio = (paper.project.view.element.width / svgWidth);
        var Hratio = (paper.project.view.element.height / svgHeight);
        return Math.min(Hratio, wRatio);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

paper.view.zoom = initialZoomRatio / window.devicePixelRatio
```

Answer (score 0):

paper.js lib provides a html attribute to add to solve the hdpi issue.
It works good for Apple Retina screens.

Have a look at paper.js [docs](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/), in the **Canvas Configuration** section, there is a setting, `hidpi="off"` or `data-paper-hidpi="off"`.

Paper.js adapts internally to this kind of screens, but sometimes has not a good result, like in my case. Just use it on the canvas tag:

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" data-paper-hidpi="off"></canvas>
```